# How can I flag a user for copying answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I came across a user who appears to be (I could be wrong) occasionally copying answers and reposting to the same question. What is the best way to flag this for moderation? 
Flag the questions "In need of moderator intervention"?

A few example questions:

[Team Agents and Admins - Apple Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258393/team-agents-and-admins-apple-developer)

[How to delete a long path in windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551072/how-to-delete-a-long-path-in-windows/4942739#4942739)

[How can I launch Safari from an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822599/how-can-i-launch-safari-from-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Hilariously, this sometimes happens several times in succession. For instance, in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/822599/464709), [the initial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/822764/464709) was plagiarized [a few months later](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1343372/464709), then the user you're referring to added [their own copy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10224319/464709) three years after, and *then* another user added [another copy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15411777/464709) one year later. All that on a no-research question. You gotta love those guys.

Comment: I've added a comment on the 2nd question, linking to the original answer. It isn't quite as obvious there as your first link ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That really is hilarious. I had no idea this was a thing. Who votes for these guys?

Comment: @Trobbins Thanks, you're right, that one was not as clear. I came across the first one by accident and so had a quick look at their other answers (assuming there would be a pattern).

Comment: My mistake: my comment wasn't due to a lack of clarity on your part, I was just commenting on the plagiarizer being so obvious in your first link :) Less so in the second

Comment: Users can upvote/downvote on posts. For stuff like this, you need the mods to intervene. So yes - flag away.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That doesn't seem to be the only instance of that - I wonder if it is a coincidence that where this user goes, other answer copies seem to follow as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340316/push-notification-device-token/10978705#10978705

Comment: At least everyone waits a year /s

Comment: @Haem, it may be a coincidence, or the other user may have seen the broken windows and decided to join the fray, or they may have observed that user's behavior and decided to emulate them. (That specific answer appears to be original, though, but of course it was plagiarized by [someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18785730/464709) later on).

Comment: @HaemEternal In that case he even copied over the bulletpoint in the code example :p

Comment: @Anzeo, that dash is actually part of the Objective C syntax I believe :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Joke's on me it seems :)

Comment: This is an abuse pattern to watch out for.  In *general* this is done by question-banned users.  They create a new account, create silly posts like these and use their banned account to vote them up.  In no time flat they are back in business.  No fantastically strong hint that this is what this guy did but it is too hard to trace back to the original banned account after this long.  Otherwise a pretty dumb way to go about it, much harder to detect this kind of abuse if they plagiarize recent Q+A and make a *bit* of effort to vary the post.  But they can't wait.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have evidence that someone is going through and copying the answers of others months or years after they have already been answered, you can let moderators know about it using a custom flag. We'll remove these answers, as I did for the ones flagged here. Make sure you indicate which is the original in your flag, because that saves us a lot of time when verifying this.

Sometimes people do swoop in and try to plagiarize existing answers for a quick reputation boost. Reviewers often don't see the context of the other answers, so they may upvote these copied answers for looking good. I've unfortunately seen a few word-for-word copied answers getting more votes than the original because of this.

Make sure there isn't something subtly different or added to these answers, though. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343372/19679) was claimed to be plagiarized from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822764/19679), but if you looked at them in their initial states, the latter actually got the method names wrong. It was only after the other, correct answer was posted that the latter one was edited to be fixed.

Comment: @Brad, you're right, I stand corrected. I got fooled by the curly braces that were added to both answers afterwards and failed to notice the wrong names were only fixed in 2010.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - You weren't the only one who got caught by this. There were a ton of deleted comments on the one answer stating this as well. History can get complex around some of these.